# php 7 MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 error in laravel homestead 32 bit

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-5

I have install laravel homestead for 32 bit in windows

```
git https://github.com/rmff/laravel-homestead-32bit.git Homestead32Bit
cd Homestead32Bit
vagrant up
```

it's working fine for me
after that i downloded laravel 5.0

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel Laravel  "~5.0.0" --prefer-dist
```

my homestead.yaml file look like this

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:\www
      to: /home/vagrant/www

sites:
    - map: daulat.app
      to: /home/vagrant/www/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Now when i'm running http://daulat.app/
i'm getting this error

```
( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' in /home/vagrant/www/Laravel/config/app.php on line 83
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0977  351248  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   1.0695  1913472 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle( )    .../index.php:53
3   1.0695  1913472 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter( )  .../compiled.php:1880
4   1.0697  1913472 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->bootstrap( ) .../compiled.php:1890
5   1.0697  1913472 Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith( ) .../compiled.php:1928
6   1.1328  1920704 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap( ) .../compiled.php:1311
7   1.1422  1920824 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles( )    .../compiled.php:1806
8   1.5877  1924344 require( '/home/vagrant/www/Laravel/config/app.php' )   .../compiled.php:1814
```

Comment: Try to run `php -m` and see if mcrypt is on the list. Try to place `phpinfo(); exit;` at the beginning of index.php and see if mcrypt is on the list

Answer (score 0):

Read the message carefully:

> ( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128'

`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` vs `'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128'`

Notice the quotes around `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`, it needs to be a string.